# What is the name of the sign used in English words derived from French words?

Tags: letters-of-the-alphabet

Consider:

> **[cliché](https://www.google.com/search?q=cliche&oq=cliche&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#)** = a phrase or opinion that is overused and betrays a lack of original thought.
>
> **[blasé](https://www.google.com/search?q=cliche&oq=cliche&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=blase)** = unimpressed with or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before.

I wanted to learn how to type that sign, the sign on the top of the ending ***e*** in above examples, by computer keyboard. I started to search about it, but soon I faced the problem that I do not know what is that sign called in English.

Comment: Rather curiously (given France is right next door to us, whereas it's thousands of miles away from America), *British* English is much more likely to discard the accent than AmE. And I must admit if I ever see an accent in, say, [***née Smith***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=n%C3%A9e+Smith%2Cnee+Smith&year_start=1962&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnee%20Smith%3B%2Cc0), my first thought is it's probably an American source. Accents aren't really "English" in England.

Comment: It is the [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) as @duskwuff has said in his/her edit to the answer by gattsbr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, it's part of a group of marks termed "[diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)". That one is an acute diacritic.

More simply, they're called "accent marks" or simply "accents".

> Diacritic is primarily an adjective, though sometimes used as a noun, whereas diacritical is only ever an adjective. Some diacritical marks, such as the acute ( ´ ) and grave ( ` ), are often called accents. Diacritical marks may appear above or below a letter, or in some other position such as within the letter or between two letters.

Answer (score 5):

The mark above the e is known as an "acute accent", in contrast to the "grave accent" which is the accent sloped the other way as in `è`.

---

On a Windows computer, you can hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, type 130 on the number pad press 130, then release <kbd>Alt</kbd> to type `é`. http://www.alt-codes.net/ lists other characters you type in this method as well.

On a Macintosh computer, you can type <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to create the acute accent, then type <kbd>e</kbd> to attach that character to the accent. The same process works for other vowels. Alternatively, you can press and hold <kbd>e</kbd> to see a list of available accented `e`s.

Comment: This doesn't help unless the OP is using the same system as you are. For example, on a Mac, all you need to do is press and hold the letter and the OS will let you pick from any of the accents available for that letter. Regardless, the question is not "how do I type this", it's "what is this called". "How do I type this" is actually off topic here.

Comment: I answered the question of "what is this called", and I went a step further with information to the original question of "how do i type this".  Further, the question states computer keyboard, but makes no mention of mac. @Catija You should read the answer fully before commenting.

Comment: You should put the *actual answer* first rather than last. Also, the terms you used are the French terms, not the English ones.

Comment: @Catija `From French words`, cliché, blasé, these are also both French words. The name of the sign over both of these, is accent aigu. Furthermore, a google search for the term `accent aigu` will bring someone to the information on how to `type it` much quicker than a google search for the term `diacritic`

Comment: I am more familiar with 'diacritical marks' / 'diacritics' than 'aigu' though. For me, it's something new. Thanks for adding this specific information.

Comment: @shin "Accent aigu" appears to be the French term for an acute accent.

Comment: @duskwuff, yes, that's noted based on the answer. Was just interested on the fact that it is specifically used for the French letter 'e'. I did check some online articles after reading the previous version of this answer, re: question examples: **cliché** and **blasé**.